# MVC Html.BeginForm CSS

Tags: asp.net, forms, css, asp.net-mvc-5

My form is not rendering css correctly in Visual Studio 2013. I am using the following code to declare the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

I have tried using this instead but still no joy:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new {@id="contact-form"}))
```

My previous HTML5 used to look like this:

```
<form id="contact-form" action" name="contact-form" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

But now, the MVC generated code is:

```
<form action="/Home/Contact/contact-form" method="post"><div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li></ul></div>
```

There is no sign of the id tag and no CSS applied to the form, also no clue where the extra code div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">

came from.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, the following code passed the CSS ID selector correctly:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "contact-form", role = "form" }))
```